# nodejs python child process immediately exits

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, process, python-import

I have two programs:

one `node.js`:

```
let spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
let childProcess = spawn('python3',["py03.py"]);


childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data){
    console.log("Data from python!: "+data.toString('ascii'));
});

childProcess.stdin.write("greetings from nodejs!\n");
```

and one Python program:

```
import sys
# from testing.py04 import Whatever

line =  input()
sys.stdout.write("Python processed: "+line)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I have commented import,
It correctly outputs

> "Data from python!: Python processed: greetings from nodejs!"

But when I import some Class it just quits.

Does anyone know why it does that? Is it something with permission?

Comment: is your python program working as standalone

Comment: @VipinKumar Did you look at python source? It's just 4 lines and yes, it works. It works even with node when I DON'T use imports.